# PHP settings from php.ini in .htaccess file - possible?

Tags: php, .htaccess, settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User Specific Php.ini When php is ran as a module?](https://serverfault.com/questions/38661/user-specific-php-ini-when-php-is-ran-as-a-module)

Hello,

I need to increase some limits for PHP but do not have access to php.ini.
The changes I need to make would look like this:

`php_value upload_max_filesize 50M`
`php_value post_max_size 50M php_value`
`max_execution_time 600 php_value`
`max_input_time 600`

Is it possible to do that in .htaccess? If it is, how?

Thank you.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/38661/user-specific-php-ini-when-php-is-ran-as-a-module

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to have a php.ini file in the directory you're working in, and those setting will override the main php.ini file. I think, I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Hi, thank you. The server-person already did that and they don't seem to be taken into account. Maybe there's an httpd.conf setting that allows/disallows this kind of configuring?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. using `php_flag` and `php_value`. Take a look on the [official manual](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) about configurations.

But wait, you already got the configs you want, you just need to put them on the `.htaccess` file!

Comment: Thank you. I already tried placing that in the .htaccess file and it generates a Server error.